# How to pass the pan gesture event from subview to parent view

Tags: ios, subview, uipangesturerecognizer

[image]

Hi guy, how can I pass only the pan gesture event from the imageView to his parent view (that is hilighted)?

Comment: What's "pass drag event" mean? What do you want to do?

Comment: Sorry, I mean it's pan gesture. Instead the UIImageView receive the pan gesture, I want to pass that gesture to his parent view.

Comment: Gesture only attach to one view. Can not pass like object.

Comment: Why don't you just add the pan gesture to the parent view itself rather than to the ImageView ?

Comment: Because I only want the uiimageview receive the gesture. In this situation, I want to drag the image around only inside the parent view.

Answer (score 1):

You could use code like the one below. It assumes that you have setup in storyboard: A view controller with a view, and within a subView to which a pan gesture recognizer has been attached, and that both `IBOutlets` and the `IBAction` have been hooked up correctly, and that the view controller is the `delegate` of the gesture recognizer.
The idea is that you store the center of the subview when you first touch it. The gesture recognizer gives you then the amount moved from this position when you pan your subview. Just try it out.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){
    CGPoint subViewCenter;
}

@property (weak) IBOutlet UIView * subView;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UIPanGestureRecognizer *myPanGestureRecognizer;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize subView;
@synthesize myPanGestureRecognizer;

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    subViewCenter = self.subView.center;
}

- (IBAction)panAction:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    CGPoint move = [sender translationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint newCenter = subViewCenter;
    newCenter.x += move.x; newCenter.y += move.y;
    subView.center = newCenter;
}

@end
```